# Material UI CSS and MuiIconButton-label

Tags: css, material-ui

Trying to target a specific span that made by the material UI IconButton component. Trying to make the text accompanying some icons to be centered below the icon, but the text is instead to the right of the icon. When I manually add flex-direction: column to this span, I get the effect I want, but I can't seem to find the right way to get the style applied in my styles.js file because I can't seem to target "MuiIconButton-label" in any permutation i've tried.

Any advice?

[browser console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZRsf.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
classes={{root: classes.icons, label: classes.icons}}
```

was the correct method